# Fluctuations in neural netwok inference time in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a neural network and I would like to test its inference time by running it on a CPU. It's important that the time would be measured as accurately as possible.

I use the following code to get the inference time of a network:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for image, _ in testloader:
        start = time.time()
        net(image)
        total_time = time.time() - start
```

The problem is, that even if I pass the same image through the network (although in this case "image" is really a batch of images) and do that many times over, the inference times will fluctuate with a difference between a minimum and maximum times reaching 30ms or even higher.

Also, before I ran the tests, I had made sure that the OS would interfere as less as possible with the process - closed all applications.

I want to understand where this fluctuations come from exactly. It is in my understanding, that if the same image is passed through the network, it should take the same time to classify it no matter how many tests I make (at least theoretically speaking).

So what causes these fluctuations? Is there a way to eliminate them?

Answer (score 0):

If you run standart torch model, torch creates graph of execution and performs some caching; this makes first run longer than others. Also I notice in several cases small difference in gc behaviour during iterations.

You can (partially) avoid these problems by converting model to TorchScript model.

Also you should check your dataloader and fix any randomness.

Comment: I can't say I noticed any increase in inference time for the first run during my tests. Also, I don't see how garbage collection would have any impact here as I'm using the same network and image in the same test while running multiple iterations. I specifically checked that the image used in the tests would always be the same - I don't think there's any randomness here.